# First-of-type selector applies to all children of a parent

Tags: css

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.wrapper > p:first-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

However, the margin property is being applied to both  elements. What's wrong?

Comment: No, it is working fine. if you add margin-left in your CSS styling, you'll get the difference.

Comment: Paragraph element `<p>` has margin-top and margin-bottom by default.

Answer (score 0):

It is not applied to the first element only, but the second element was not applied to it
And even if applied to it you did not notice that because the margin is down and the last element

Answer (score 0):

There are two extra rules you can put into your CSS that will show you that your first-of-type selector is working correctly. Firstly, you can add

```
* {
  margin: 0
}
```

Most browsers, by default, add a margin-top and margin-bottom to all `<p>` elements. If you do not explicitly eliminate this, sometimes called a CSS reset, it will always be used. getting rid of it allows you to see that only your top `<p>` element has a margin on the bottom.

If you still have trouble seeing this, you can add

```
p {
  border: 1px solid green
}
```

Having a border will show you more clearly that the top paragraph has a margin and the bottom one does not. Add a third `<p>` for the result to stand out more starkly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}
.wrapper > p:first-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid green
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```